# Extracting from a file and pasting details to another file

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal, nmap

The problem is regarding extracting the details of the Oracle Virtual box(2nd paragraph) from the **"nmap non-gui version"**. I understand the usage of **"grep"** and **"loops"** and have already tried everything but what if there are other systems connected on the same network. I just want the program to find the word ***"(Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)"*** and extract everything above it until it finds a blank-line.

```
**
```

> root@PopeyeTheSailorMan:~# nmap 192.168.43.0/24 > Log.txt

**

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-11-15 04:08 UTC
Nmap scan report for 192.168.43.1
Host is up (0.0025s latency).
Not shown: 999 closed ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
53/tcp open  domain
MAC Address: 9A:10:94:51:42:ED (Unknown)

***Nmap scan report for 192.168.43.136
Host is up (0.00071s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
443/tcp  open  https
1024/tcp open  kdm
MAC Address: 08:00:27:D3:73:2E (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)***

Nmap scan report for kali (192.168.43.79)
Host is up (0.0000070s latency).
All 1000 scanned ports on kali (192.168.43.79) are closed

Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (3 hosts up) scanned in 16.00 seconds
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, this does what you want:

```
awk '/Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC/' RS= Log.txt
```

With your sample input:

```
$ awk '/Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC/' RS= Log.txt
***Nmap scan report for 192.168.43.136
Host is up (0.00071s latency).
Not shown: 994 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
111/tcp  open  rpcbind
139/tcp  open  netbios-ssn
443/tcp  open  https
1024/tcp open  kdm
MAC Address: 08:00:27:D3:73:2E (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)***
```

#### How it works

- `RS=`

  This tells awk to read input a paragraph at a time.
- `/Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC/`

  This tells awk to print any paragraph that contains the string `Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Marked as the best answer and accepted :)

Answer (score 1):

```
    grep -n ^$ Log.txt | sed s/://
```

will give the blank line numbers (suitable for an array)

```
    grep -n 'Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC' Log.txt | cut -f1 -d\:
```

will give the line numbers of the target

Use arrays, loops and sed to grok the block you want

```
    sed -n '8,19p' Log.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the deep explanation @sos .  But,what I was looking for was precisely answered by **John1024** . You can check it if you want :)